# Re-writing collection-populating simulation in Scala in a functional way

Tags: scala, list, functional-programming, simulation

Take a very simple simulation where we are modelling a person's survival or death in a year - based on a generated random number we decide whether the person survives a year or not:

```
case class PersonEntry(pid: Long, year: Short, age: Short, status: Byte) {

  // return an entry where person survives and gets 1 year older
  def Mature(): PersonEntry = {
    PersonEntry(pid, (year + 1).toShort, (age + 1).toShort, status)
  }

  // return an entry where person dies (status is 0)
  def Kill(): PersonEntry = {
    PersonEntry(pid, (year + 1).toShort, (age + 1).toShort, 0)
  }

  // based on a random number decide if return Matured or Killed
  def Simulate(p: Double = 0.5): PersonEntry = {
    val rnd = scala.util.Random
    if (rnd.nextDouble < p) this.Mature() else this.Kill() 
  }

}
```

Based on this we can get a new entry for the same person which simulates 1 year with the probability of survival of 95%:

```
val per1 = PersonEntry(1, 2018, 20, 1)
val per2 = per1.Simulate(0.95)
```

What we would like to do next is to create a simulation for an arbitrary amount of years. What I created so far for this is a very straight-forward approach:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

case class PersonSimulation(entries: ListBuffer[PersonEntry]) {
 def Simulate(n: Int = 1, p: Double = 0.5): Unit = {
   for (i <- List.range(1, n)) {
     this.entries += this.entries.last.Simulate(p)
   }
 }
}
```

Now we can do:

```
val per = PersonEntry(1, 2018, 20, 1)
val sim = PersonSimulation(ListBuffer(per))
sim.Simulate(100, 0.95)

// look at the result
println(sim)
```

The `PersonSimulation.Simulate` method does the job, but is not functional at all as it adds new elements to the `entries` `ListBuffer`.

How can we efficiently rewrite the `PersonSimulation` in a functional way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly the same signature as `Simulate`, but you can do this kind of thing fairly elegantly with the `iterate` method you'll find on `List`, `Stream`, etc.:

```
val entry = PersonEntry(1, 2018, 20, 1)
val entries = List.iterate(entry, 100)(_.Simulate(0.95))
```

This says "start with `entry`, call `.Simulate(0.95)` on it, then call `.Simulate(0.95)` on the result you get, and then on that result, for 100 times in a row, collecting the results in a list", which looks for example like this:

```
scala> entries.foreach(println)
PersonEntry(1,2018,20,1)
PersonEntry(1,2019,21,1)
PersonEntry(1,2020,22,1)
PersonEntry(1,2021,23,1)
PersonEntry(1,2022,24,1)
PersonEntry(1,2023,25,1)
PersonEntry(1,2024,26,1)
PersonEntry(1,2025,27,1)
PersonEntry(1,2026,28,1)
PersonEntry(1,2027,29,1)
PersonEntry(1,2028,30,1)
PersonEntry(1,2029,31,1)
PersonEntry(1,2030,32,1)
PersonEntry(1,2031,33,0)
PersonEntry(1,2032,34,0)
...
```

With `Stream` you don't even have to set the number of iterations in advance:

```
val entries = Stream.iterate(entry)(_.Simulate(0.95))
```

Now you have an infinite stream of years in your simulation, which you can take a chunk of to look at:

```
scala> entries.take(10).foreach(println)
PersonEntry(1,2018,20,1)
PersonEntry(1,2019,21,1)
PersonEntry(1,2020,22,1)
PersonEntry(1,2021,23,1)
PersonEntry(1,2022,24,1)
PersonEntry(1,2023,25,1)
PersonEntry(1,2024,26,0)
PersonEntry(1,2025,27,0)
PersonEntry(1,2026,28,0)
PersonEntry(1,2027,29,0)
```

Note that neither of these solutions is *purely* functional, since you're relying on a random number generator, and you'll get a different result each time you run the program, but it's functional in the sense that it avoids using a mutable collection to collect the results.

Comment: Fantastic, this is exactly what I was looking for, Thank you!

Comment: With the `val entries = Stream.iterate(entry)(_.Simulate(0.95))` approach, if I wanted to pass not a single `0.95`, but an array element (e.g. `p` is an array of 100 probabilities) - a different one in each iteration, is this possible? Could not figure this out looking at the docs.

Comment: @Jozef It's worth another question, but I'd probably use `scan` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use functional way - use immutable data structures.
Use method copy for case classes.
You create another case class but you can create implicit method.

Here we are:

```
import scala.util.Random

case class PersonEntry(pid: Long, year: Short, age: Short, status: Byte) {

  // return an entry where person survives and gets 1 year older
  def Mature: PersonEntry = {
    copy(year = (year + 1).toShort, age = (age + 1).toShort)
  }

  // return an entry where person dies (status is 0)
  def Kill: PersonEntry = {
    copy(year = (year + 1).toShort, age = (age + 1).toShort, status = 0)
  }

  // based on a random number decide if return Matured or Killed
  def Simulate(p: Double = 0.5): PersonEntry = {
    val rnd = Random.nextDouble
    if (rnd < p) Mature else Kill
  }

}

implicit class PersonListExt(l: List[PersonEntry]) {
  def simulate(n: Int = 1, p: Double = 0.5): Map[Int, List[PersonEntry]] = {
    (1 to n).map(_ -> l.map(_.Simulate(p))).toMap
  }
}

val simulateMap: Map[Int, List[PersonEntry]]  = (1 to 10).map(i =>
  PersonEntry(i, 2018.toShort, Random.nextInt(50).toShort, 1)
).toList.simulate()
```